# How to retrieve just the thumbnail and the origin size of an image from a url that contains an image ?

Tags: iphone

i want to make a tool to load all images from a website  running on my IOS device.
but i would like to filter out the images which are small from those.

So, I have to get the size of the image , 
How to retrieve just the thumbnail and the origin size of an image from a url that contains an image ? 
 make sure not do this after loading the entire images, get these data directly requesting the url .)

any feedback or answer will be appreciated ~.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow isn't really intended for questions like this. Instead you need to break the problem down.

1. Access a URL and download the data.
2. Convert that data into an image type so you can determine it's dimensions
3. Discard any images that are two large.

I know without even looking that there are countless tutorials on how to complete step 1. Step 2 may be a bit more difficult but I'm skeptical this is the case. Do a few Google searches, try some stuff out and then come back if you have more questions.

Comment: Also if someone gives you a helpful answer you should upvote. Some of us put our profiles on our resumes and cover letters when we're trying to find work so your votes are important to us. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do that without more specific access to HTTP request headers. The idea would be to only download enough data to have access to the image header, where the image size is stored. But from there on you can only really limit the data transfered if the image format supports it. In other words, you need a JPEG, GIF or PNG in interlaced/progressive encoding mode to be able to limit data at all. Additionally you need to be able to decode partially transfered images.

If you're doing this via HTML/JavaScript then the answer is way shorter: It's not possible without downloading the entire image.

Comment: hehe~ that seems to be more complicated ~ i 'll try .